# How write an npm package that supports every JavaScript environments (module systems)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

For the last couple of weeks I've been working on a utility library and now I want to publish it on npm for other people to use.

The library doesn't use any node specific features except the commonjs module system. It's written in pure es6 and doesn't have any dependency. I want it to be compatible with both front-end (vanilla JavaScript, react etc.) and also for back-end in Nodejs.

I already looked up a few articles about this but they used babel, webpack some talked about rollup and bower... I'm only familiar babel and webpack but I don't know how to use them for this project (but I'm willing to learn those technologies if needed).

I just need some hint how to move forward from this point. Please give me some suggestion on this topic.

Thanks is advance <3. I highly appreciate your efforts on `StackOverflow`.

Comment: I wrote a small, self-contained library that's for both Node and has a webpack build. I use it as a template now every time I write a new lib. Maybe it's of use to you: https://github.com/evert/bigint-money .  Feel free to contact me with questions. I doubt you get a good answer here because you're asking for training/tutorial rather than a specific question that has a specific answer.

Comment: @Evert thanks for quick response. I'll surely check your project.

Comment: Hey @Evert, sorry to bother you. I checked out your bigint-money project and I'm confused about lots of things. Could you kindly guide me to the resources that I need to learn to build packages like you? I already know JavaScript, Typescript, React and Node. What else do I need to learn?

Comment: I would recommend you learn how to ask specific, pointed questions =)

Comment: Sorry about that. I think my question is: `How to configure an npm package (written in JS or TS) that when it is downloaded(or before downloading) its code gets converted as such it supports both node and react environment?` Or sth else I really don't know. I'm just a noob and in contrast you're a senior. You know the whole process of publishing a npm package. And I don't wanna waste your time. That's why I'm asking you to give me some hint about what to learn. Hope you'd be kind enough to give some advices.

Comment: That's a great question. Usually when you publish a package, the typescript building happens *before* building. So if you look at my package.json, there's a 'prepublishOnly' script. This causes the ts files to be built right before you call `npm publish`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The answer was:** use a **module bundler** like webpack, rollup, gulp etc.
that bundles all of your modules with the **umd** module system.

Well, it took me a little longer to figure out and learn all these stuff then I
expected. Finally, I got some free time to write about it, in case someone finds
it useful!

### My Project Structure

```
.
├── dist
├── src
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── interface.ts
│   └── util.ts
├── tests
│   ├── index.test.ts
│   └── util.test.ts
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
├── package-lock.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

### My `tsconfig.json` file

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5",

    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",

    "declaration": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["./src/*"]
}
```

Now, we need to bundle all the the modules in the `/src` directory into a single
module `index.js` in the `/dist` directory. To do this we'll use use a popular
module bundler called **webpack**.

But if we want that bundle file to be supported in every JavaScript environment
i.e., every JS **module systems** (commonjs, es6, amd, etc.) then we
need to use the [umd](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) **(Universal Module
Definition)** module system. Luckily, almost every module bundler can take care
of that.

Install `webpack` and `ts-loader` (to transpile TypeScript to JavaScript) as
dev-dependency (with the `-D` option).

```sh
npm i -D webpack webpack-cli ts-loader
```

My `webpack` and `ts-loader` versions

```json
{
  "webpack": "^5.65.0",
  "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
  "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
}
```

### My `webpack.config.js`

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: "./src/index.ts", // entry point of our project

  module: {
    rules: [

      // use ts-loader to transpile .ts files
      {
        test: /\.ts/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },

    ],
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts"],
  },

  output: {
    // empty the output directory on every build
    clean: true,

    // the dir of output bundle
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),

    // output bundle name
    filename: "index.js",

    globalObject: "this",

    library: {
      // your lib name if imported with the <script> tag
      // for this library it will be available as `window.char_series`
      name: "char_series", 

      // the module type
      type: "umd",

      export: "default",
    },
  },
};
```

Kindly refer to the `webpack` [docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/) for
detailed explanation. Also read their
[Authoring Libraries](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#root)
guide.

To build (bundle) this library, we can run the `webpack` command in terminal
or we can automate this process with **npm scripts**.

### Script section of `package.json`

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest",
  "build": "webpack",
  "prepublishOnly": "npm test && npm run build"
}
```

Here I'm using `jest` for testing. After adding this script section in our
`package.json` we can run `npm test` and `npm run build` to test and build our
project respectively. The command in the `"prepublishOnly"` field takes care of
testing and building the project every time we publish the project with
`npm publish`.

With the above configuration I've published a small library on npm called
`char-series`. See it on [github](https://www.npmjs.com/package/char-series).

I hope you find this post useful and thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

A low tech solution is to create a single variable that provides the complete API or API endpoints provided by the package script when loaded in a browser. If need be write the package inside an IIFE to prevent package variables polluting the browser's global address space.

Additionally test if the script has been required in node as a commonJS module and export the API using commonJS hooks if it has:

```
var myAPI = (()=>{
   var exports = {}
   //...
   exports.foo = "foo";
   //...
   return exports;
})();

// export myAPI if running in node

if( typeof module == "object" && module && module.exports
 && this && this === module.exports
 && typeof require == "function") {
    module.exports = myAPI;
}
```

*The not-so-well-known part of the node signature is that commonJS modules are called with their `this` object set to `module.exports`.*

This approach was developed as a workaround for [you can't run JS modules via a file:// URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) - if the restrictions on module use are acceptable consider using JS modules directly.

While aware of more complicated methods to handle a wider range of usage environments, I have not seen descriptions of how they work. If readers have insights into better or more general solutions I would welcome reading additional answers.

---

You can also tell node that a JavaScript file with a `.js` extension is actually an es6 module by including

```
  "type": "module",
```

in the root (JSON) object of the project's `package.json` file - which for a package containing a single script should be all that is needed.

To actually use a module file in node, ensure that the main application script file has been given an `mjs` extension (so it can use `import` statements without throwing errors), or in a commonJS environment  import the module using an [import expression](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/esm.html#esm_import_expression).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I already knew this approach but the problem is node doesn't support es6 import and export syntax without the `.mjs` file extension. If I use es6 syntax then how the library would work with node? Is there any mechanism such as when someone downloads the library from npm, after downloading it a npm script will run automatically so all the import and export statements gets automatically converted (by webpack or babel may be?) for the correct environment?

Comment: @h-sifat Interestingly it turns out you _can_ use  the `.js` extension for module files in node and for your case it may be all that you need - see the updated answer for details.

Comment: That's interesting. One little question! I learned that this is supported only after node version >= 13. Should I worry about my library being compatible with older versions of node?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much if I were you - most users update node to keep up with latest features they want to use, or when installing it on a new machine or to refresh a device after software failure. An example in the readme file of importing it in a commonJS module may benefit potential users the most.